# Google apps script, how to create an event object script that activates when you change the name of a sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, synchronization

I am attempting to create an onEdit type script that connects two sheets so that if the name of one of the sheets gets changed the other also gets changed. My idea so far was to maybe use the "oldValue" compared to the "value" in an if else operation but I cant figure out a way to get it to work.

If it can't be done then that's fine but if it can then I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

:)

Comment: Consider using developer metadata

Comment: The [installable onChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) responds to sheet name changes.

Comment: @Cooper hello again, what would the 'changeType' be for renaming a sheet, I tried using "Logger.log(e.changeType());" but I wasn't getting any logs, am I just completely barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Interestingly enough I looked at that earlier and it was just 'other'.  Not very informative.  But I added a function that should help you get started on fulfilling your specific needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's a simple onChange function that will get the old sheet name and the new sheet name when a sheets name is changed by the user.**

The first function just set's up the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service). It should be run just to create the 'oshts' property.

```
function setupPropertyoshts() {
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('oshts', SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().map(function(sheet){return sheet.getName()}).join(','));
  Logger.log(PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('oshts'));
}
```

This is the function that you attach to the onChange [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).  I left all of the Logger.logs and the toast that I used for debugging it in the script.

```
function sheetNameChange(e) {
  var cshts=e.source.getSheets().map(function(sheet){return sheet.getName()});
  var oshts=PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('oshts').split(',');
  Logger.log('cshts: %s oshts: %s',cshts,oshts);
  var oldName=oshts[cshts.indexOf(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName())];
  Logger.log('oldName; %s newName: %s',oldName,e.source.getActiveSheet().getName());
  e.source.toast(Utilities.formatString('The old name was %s. The new name is %s.',oldName,e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()));
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('oshts',cshts.join(','));
}
```

#### Other References

1. [onChange Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)
2. [SpreadsheetApp Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
3. [JavaScript Array.map reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
4. [Managing Triggers Manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)
5. [Managing Triggers Programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically)

Comment: Cooper I feel like you have helped me a ridiculous amount and I don't know how to say thank you enough, I've tested the code and it all works perfectly, I don't understand all of it right now but I'm gonna go away and do some research to figure that out. :)

Comment: That's a great idea.  When I'm programming and  I run into a problem I usually start thinking of developing a minimal complete and verifiable question of my own.  Sometimes that helps me solve my problem and sometimes it becomes a question for this site.  At any rate take the time to read this carefully [mcve]